# Trouble with SQL query and php

Tags: mysql

I'm at the stage where I'm just starting to understand PHP and MySQL but I am stuck. I have been studying a tutorial from developphp.com in which Shawn's WI is building a message system

```
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLgsYR-L3Uwbps9E-xIQPajQOiZVbOo6lr
```

I am trying to redesign the tutorial so it fits my needs. i have built a mail page called pm_inbox.php which works fine, it gives me mail that has been sent to me in a DESC order.

pm_inbox.php

```
$sql = "SELECT pm.*, u.avatar, u.country 
FROM pm AS pm
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.username = pm.sender
WHERE (pm.receiver='$u' AND pm.parent='x' AND pm.rdelete='0')
OR (pm.sender='$u' AND pm.sdelete='0' AND pm.parent='x' AND pm.hasreplies='1')
ORDER BY senttime DESC";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$statusnumrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
// Gather data about parent pm's
if($statusnumrows > 0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $pmid = $row["id"];
        //div naming
        $pmid2 = 'pm_'.$pmid;
        $wrap1 = 'pm_message_wrap_'.$pmid;
        //button naming
        $btid2 = 'bt_'.$pmid;
        //textarea naming
        $rt = 'replytext_'.$pmid;
        //button naming
        $rb = 'replyBtn_'.$pmid;
        $receiver = $row["receiver"];
        $sender = $row["sender"];
        $subject = $row["subject"];
        $message = $row["message"];
        $time = $row["senttime"];
        $rread = $row["rread"];
        $sread = $row["sread"];
        $avatar = $row["avatar"];
        $country = $row["country"];

        // Start to build our list of parent pm's
        $mail .= '<div id="'.$wrap1.'" class="pm_message_wrap">';
        $mail .= '<table id="inboxMailMessages" width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
    <td width="6%"><input name="toggleAll" id="toggleAll" type="checkbox"/></td>
    <td width="19%"><a href="user.php?u='.$sender.'" title="'.$sender.'"><img src="user/'.$sender.'/'.$avatar.'"width=100" height="100" border="0" /></a></td>
    <td width="75%">
    <div class="inboxmailRollover">
    <p class="mailboxp">Subject: ' .$subject. '<br></p>
    <p class="mailboxp"><a href="user.php?u=' . $sender . '">From:'.$sender. '</a><br></p>
    <p class="mailboxp"><a href="inboxMain.php?u=' . $u . '">' .$country. '</a><br></p>
    <p class="mailboxp">' .$message. '</p>
    </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>';
        $mail .= '<hr>';
        $mail .= '</div>';
```

what i am trying to do is when someone clicks the country link on pm_inbox.php it will take them through to another page called inboxMain.php in which it will show the persons details in a container who has sent the mail as in the sender, the subject and the country.

i have 4 mail on pm_inbox.php that people have sent me. when i push on the country link it takes me through to inboxMain.php but instead of showing me just the persons details that has sent me the mail it shows all 4 peoples details in 4 separate containers. i know it is a sql query problem on inboxMain.php but cant work it out. i wonder if someone can help me please.

inboxMain.php

```
$sql = "SELECT pm., u.avatar, u.country 
FROM pm AS pm
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.username = pm.sender
WHERE pm.id='$pmid' AND pm.sender='$u' AND pm.sdelete='0' AND pm.parent='x'";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$statusnumrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
// Gather data about parent pm's
if($statusnumrows > 0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $pmid = $row["id"];
        //div naming
        $pmid2 = 'pm_'.$pmid;
        $wrap2 = 'reply_profile_wrap'.$pmid;
        //button naming
        $btid2 = 'bt_'.$pmid;
        //textarea naming
        $rt = 'replytext_'.$pmid;
        //button naming
        $rb = 'replyBtn_'.$pmid;
        $receiver = $row["receiver"];
        $sender = $row["sender"];
        $subject = $row["subject"];
        $message = $row["message"];
        $time = $row["senttime"];
        $rread = $row["rread"];
        $sread = $row["sread"];
        $avatar = $row["avatar"];
        $country = $row["country"];

        // Start to build our list of parent pm's
        $reply_profile .= '<div id="'.$wrap2.'" class="reply_profile_wrap">';
        $reply_profile .= '<table id="replyProfile" width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="19%"><a href="user.php?u='.$sender.'" title="'.$sender.'"><img src="user/'.$sender.'/'.$avatar.'"width=75" height="75" border="0" /></a></td>
    <td>    
    <p class="replyProfilep">Subject: ' .$subject. '<br></p>
    <p class="replyProfilep"><a href="user.php?u=' . $sender . '">From:'.$sender. '</a><br></p>
    <p class="replyProfilep">Country: ' .$country. '</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>';

        $reply_profile .= '</div>';
```

Comment: If you just want one message, put `$pmid` in the URL parameter. Then use `WHERE pm.id = $id`.

Comment: hi Barmar. thank you so much for your answer it is very kind of you. May be i wasnt clear enough with my question which was my fault and sorry but what i am really looking for is my mail page is ok. what i was really trying to do is when pushing on the mail where country is i wanted to go through to that persons pm.id in which the mail is instead of having all 4 pm.id's i know it has something to do with the sql query on the inboxMain page that is recieving the results

Answer (score 0):

Put a link that gets the specific `pm.id` around the country.

```
<p class="replyProfilep"><a href="mail.php?id=' . $pmid . '">Country: ' .$country. '</a></p>
```

Then in `mail.php` you can use a query like:

```
$pmid = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT pm.*, u.avatar, u.country 
    FROM pm AS pm
    LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.username = pm.sender
    WHERE pm.id = $pmid";
```

Comment: hi Barmar. we spoke about 4 days ago in which i put a question down and it wasnt making sense. sorry it has taken me this long to get back. i have just re-edit my question and deleted the question i put in the answer section. i am just finding my way around the site and wonder now i have updated it if it was possible for you to have a look. many thanks if you can.

Comment: The query in `inboxMain.php` looks identical to the one in `pm_inbox.php`. So of course it's displaying the same information.

Comment: hi Barmar, sorry to be annoying. i have changed the query in inboxMain.php. i have been trying all day to try and work it out but unable to. i do appreciated you help fella, it is very kind of you and i wondered if you had any idea how i could go about this code problem, many thanks.

Comment: I still can't figure out what you're trying to do. If you want to see the person's details, why are you querying the `pm` table instead of just the `users` table?

Comment: Where does `$pmid` come from in `inboxMain.php`?

Comment: thanks for your reply Barmar. i thought if i put the output in a div with $pmid around a container called class="reply_profile_wrap" it would get the sender through the id. what i am trying to do is when someone clicks on the country link it would send me to inboxMain.php with the sender, subject and country of the user that sent that mail wrapped in a container. i do appreciate all your help.

Comment: The only information it gets in `inboxMain.php` are the parameters in the URL, which is `u=$sender`. In `inboxMain.php` you can access this with `$u = $_GET['u']`. But there's no `$pmid` because you didn't send that in the URL.

Comment: I think you need to read a good tutorial that explains how this all works. You're not going to get it by trial and error like this, and I can't teach a class on web programming in the comments section here.

Comment: i know how it works Barmar i just cant get the query right to output the sender, subject and country of the mail that i am clicking in to. but thank you very much for your help anyway.

Comment: If you knew how it works, you wouldn't be trying to use `$pmid` when it hasn't been sent as a parameter.

Comment: no problem Barmar. perhaps i will do a little bit more learning tomorrow. i thought i was getting the hang of this lol but it is hard. i understand how it all works just finding it hard to work out and put down. By parameter is it on the pm_inbox.php where i am going wrong isnt it? should i have something like <p class="mailboxp"><a href="inboxMain.php?u=id' instead of just <p class="mailboxp"><a href="inboxMain.php?u='       ?

Comment: Variables in one script don't carry over to another script. When `pm_inbox.php` links to `inboxMain.php`, everything starts fresh.

Comment: yes but i thought gobal Variables could be used around every page? is that just in javascript? i will change all the Variables tomorrow on the inboxMain.php and have another go tomorrow. i understand what your saying now and i appreciate every bit of advice you give me. thank you.

Comment: That's Javascript, because the global variable context is the browser page. PHP is run on the server, and every script gets its own variables. You can use session variables to pass data from one script to the next.

Comment: Thanks for your help Barmar, i will have another crack at it tomorrow. enjoy your evening.